# How to catch error code 500 with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would ask you something,

How to test if there is error 500 file in a web?

Is there any sugesstion for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to check the response code using Selenium Webdriver. Refer this [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141).

To check the response code you'll have to send a request using [`java.net.HttpUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (or any other HTTP library) and then check the response code.

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33339188/2932244) which will give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: and how about another automation tools?